# Improving Query Performance on Non-Indexed Single HEAP File DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, enterprise-edition

My teammates and I often have to write queries that revolve around a database that is not partitioned (a single heap file) and has no index. I was told by the DBA that this won't change. Are there techniques we can use that would help us in query performance or is it a it is what it is? For example there is a table that has just north of 54 million rows in it and it takes almost 40 seconds to get the answer to `select count(*) from dbo.table`

This is in SSMS.

Queries against these tables coming back with maybe 2,000 records with simple filters of `columnA = 'this' and date is >= 'this date'` take a few minutes.

Comment: I tried to talk to the DBA to see if they can be defined and if they can be partitioned, they said no and basically don't ask again. I'm just the user. Queries against these tables coming back with maybe 2000 records with simple filters of columnA = 'this' and date is >= 'this date' take a few minutes.

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server are you using? SELECT @@VERSION; should answer.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-GDR) (KB5021129) - 13.0.6430.49 (X64)   Jan 22 2023 17:38:22   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: You should find out from your DBA why they don't want to index the table. That's pretty much the solution to your problem. Without an index, the whole table (all 54 million rows) will always be scanned first before it can be filtered down to the few rows your query cares about. Without a valid reason from the DBA, it sounds like they just don't want to do their job or are knowledgeable enough.

Comment: If you want the row count you might be better off querying: select rows from sys.partitions where object_id = OBJECT_ID('table') and index_id = 0;

Comment: This sounds more like a workplace.se question than an dba.se question TBH. On the assumption that the queries you are doing are worthwhile then you should probably escalate it as what is currently provided by the DBA doesn't sound fit for the purpose you are using it for. So you need to understand what the arguments against indexing the table are and whether indexes **can** feasibly be added or maybe the data provided in some alternative way

Comment: ok, so seems like it is what it is, thanks everyone